# Cmake directory error

Tags: command-line

When trying to execute the follow in a Terminal window:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE
        -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
        -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON
        -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF
        -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON
        -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/projects/cv2/opencv_contrib/modules
        -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/env/bin/python
        -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON …/opencv
```

I get an error message on the last statement saying “source directory does not exist”. What should be put in the place of the two `…/opencv`?

When I tried the command `echo $(which python)`, I received the message `/home/jetson/env/bin/python`.

What is the issue and how do i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a directory as parameter for `cmake`, it will change into that directory and searches for the `CMakeLists.txt` file. See also the [cmake manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/cmake.1.html) for more information.

In your command, you specified and invalid directory: `…/opencv`. Three dots is not a valid directory in Linux. You propaly need to change it into `../opencv` to work. But It really depends, where the `opencv` folder is